# What is the right way to format a mathematical formula?

Tags: discussion, formatting

The question ["Did Euler make the elementary mistake […]"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47874/did-euler-make-the-elementary-mistake-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-sqrt-6) sees something like [a micro edit war](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/47874/revisions) centered around the formatting of the title. The original post used pseudo-math mode to represent the square root symbol:

> Did Euler make the elementary mistake sqrt{-2} sqrt{-3} = sqrt{6}?

A subsequent edit by a new user (approved by two users with some experience on skeptics.SE) changed this to syntactically valid LaTex math mode:

> Did Euler make the elementary mistake $\sqrt{-2} \sqrt{-3} = \sqrt{6}$?

Soon after, the title was changed again by another relatively new user by employing "Unicode instead of pseudo-TeX". The same two users who approved the previous edit also approved this edit:

> Did Euler make the elementary mistake √-2 √-3 = √6?

Today, nine months later, the title was edited yet another time by a new user back to the LaTex math mode format. The user who approved this edit is the author of the original question.

Even though I can read math mode myself, I think its use is detrimental to the readability and accessibility of the site if valid alternatives like Unicode representations exist. But is there a consensus on this issue? Which way of formatting mathematical formulas is preferred on skeptics.SE?

Comment: Note: Rolled back the change, and imposed a lock for 24 hours while this is considered.

Comment: The [editor](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/58708/strawberry-sunshine) who made that change has 4K rep on math.SE and 103 here, so they probably assumed (incorrectly) that LaTeX works here (too).

Comment: @Fizz That's a misconception I see at least four or five times a year on various SEs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want titles to be readable by the widest audience possible. Therefore, if there is a representation that the site can use to display the actual symbol, then that is the way to go.

For math symbols, some SE sites support [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but [Skeptics.SE does not](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3990/can-we-enable-tex), so Unicode √ is the best we have.